# Password check without using RegEx and/or lists/rules

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

I've searched the forums and all over google and have yet to find an answer to my question. I'd like to create a simple program with one single for loop with if/if else statements. Is this possible without using RegEx or lists/rules?

I'd like it to fit these requirements:

Length 8.
At least one digit.
At least one upper case.
At least one lower case.

This is what I've come up with thus far and I don't understand why it doesn't work? The reason I have the if statements without else if's is because I want all error messages to printed if the conditions are not met. Apologies for dumb questions, I'm new to c#.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var password = Console.ReadLine();

    for (var i = 0; i < password.Length; ++i)
    {
        bool hasDigit = char.IsDigit(password[i]);
        bool hasUpperCase = char.IsUpper(password[i]);
        bool hasLowerCase = char.IsLower(password[i]);

        if(password.Length < 8)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Password length should be 8 symbols or more.");
        }
        if(!hasUpperCase)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one uppercase letter.");
        }
        if(!hasLowerCase)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one lowercase letter.");
        }
        if(!hasDigit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one digit.");
        }

        password = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Your password is properly set!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Step through your code [in the debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and you will see what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your if statements are trying to check whether the password contains upper/lower/digit for each iteration of the loop, so you are actually only checking one letter at a time.

You also don't have anything which would break the loop if the password is actually correct so it asks you to re-enter it each time.

Think you're after something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var password = Console.ReadLine();
    bool passwordCorrect = false;

    while (!passwordCorrect)
    {
        bool hasDigit = false;
        bool hasUpperCase = false;
        bool hasLowerCase = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < password.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(password[i]))
                hasDigit = true;

            if (char.IsUpper(password[i]))
                hasUpperCase = true;

            if (char.IsLower(password[i]))
                hasLowerCase = true;
        }

        if (password.Length >= 8 
            && hasUpperCase 
            && hasLowerCase 
            && hasDigit)
        {
            passwordCorrect = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(password.Length < 8)
                Console.WriteLine("Password length should be 8 symbols or more.");

            if(!hasUpperCase)
                Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one uppercase letter.");

            if(!hasLowerCase)
                Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one lowercase letter.");

            if(!hasDigit)
                Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one digit.");

            password = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Your password is properly set!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

dotnetfiddle available here so you can see if it works as you expected:
[dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ICguiZ)

Comment: Thank you for this! Really helped me understand what I did wrong :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is checking a single char every turn. This means that only one bool will return true. You should instead made the check outside the loop, like:

```
bool hasDigit = false;
bool hasUpperCase = false;
bool hasLowerCase = false;
for (var i = 0; i < password.Length; ++i)
{
    hasDigit = hasDigit || char.IsDigit(password[i]);
    hasUpperCase = hasUpperCase || char.IsUpper(password[i]);
    hasLowerCase = hasLowerCase || char.IsLower(password[i]);   
}
if(password.Length < 8)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password length should be 8 symbols or more.");
}
if(!hasUpperCase)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one uppercase letter.");
}
if(!hasLowerCase)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one lowercase letter.");

}
if(!hasDigit)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one digit.");
}
```

Another option is use linq, so you don't need the for loop, like this:

```
if(password.Length < 8)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password length should be 8 symbols or more.");
}
if(!password.Any(x=>char.IsUpper(x)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one uppercase letter.");
}
if(!password.Any(x=>char.IsLower(x)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one lowercase letter.");        
}
if(!password.Any(x=>char.IsDigit(x)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one digit.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use linq to do the checks is more easy than looping over all characters and is more clean code:

```
if(password.Length < 8)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password length should be 8 symbols or more.");
}
if(!password.Any(char.IsUpper))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one uppercase letter.");
}
if(!password.Any(char.IsLower))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one lowercase letter.");

}
if(!password.Any(char.IsDigit))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Password should contain at least one digit.");
}
```